# Why can't I target my footer image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, footer

```css
.footer_image {
  height: 60rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer_image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" style="margin-left:20px">
  </div>
</footer>
```

I cant seem to target the properties to change my image in my footer, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code appears to be working as expected.  Can you elaborate on the problem you're observing?

Comment: If you want to target the image itself, why not use `.footer_image img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.footer_image img {
}
```

This will work on all pictures which have the html `img` tag and are inside the `.footer_image` class

Or you can assign a class or id to your image to define its properties

```
<img class="mysuperfancyimage" src="logo_footer.png" style="margin-left:20px">
```

```
<img id="mysuperfancyimage" src="logo_footer.png" style="margin-left:20px">
```

You can call classes with a dot and and IDs with a Rhombus

```
.mysuperfancyimage {
}
```

```
#mysuperfancyimage {
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I must have overlooked some properties and thought I was doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely - the problem might be that you're targeting the image parent, not the image itself.

```css
.footer_image > img {
    height: 60rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer_image">
    <img src="logo_footer.png" style="margin-left:20px">
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this earlier but must have slipped up somewhere